# How to correlate on sharp data changes

Tags: time-series, correlation, medicine

I'm trying to correlate changes in atmospheric pressure with headache intensity. I 'know' that there is a strong correlation in my case but out of curiosity I'm willing to take data for as long as I care.
I'm taking daily pressure data and registering headache intensity in the range 1-4 (no pain to pain strong enough to take painkillers).
The dataset looks like this:

| Date | Atm. pressure | Headache intensity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/2 | 1011 mbar | 1 pain |
| 9/3 | 1011 mbar | 1 pain |
| 9/4 | 1014 mbar | 4 pain |
| 9/5 | 1016 mbar | 4 pain |
| 9/6 | 1016 mbar | 1 pain |
| 9/7 | 1015 mbar | 2 pain |

And so on. As far as I know, the correlation lies in sharp changes of pressure, not in the fact that there is more or less pressure in a given day.
How could I study this correlation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to take the absolute value of the difference of each pressure value to its last value $\Delta p(t) = p(t)-p(t-1)$ and then calculate the correlation between this finite difference and the pain value.

Comment: Omg it didn't occur to me, it is so straightforward and effective. Thanks!